# Multiple search inputs to output as one search in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, search

I'm trying to create a search box that would have 4 inputs but output as one search. Here is my current code:

```
 <form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://sitename.com/">
 <input type="text"  name="s" />
 <input type="text" name="a" />
 <input type="text"  name="b" />
 <input type="text"  name="c" />
 <div class="clear_space"></div>
 <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
 </form>
```

But that outputs like this in wordpress: /?s=milk&a=eggs&b=cheese&c=garlic&submit=Search

But I need it to output like this: /?s=milk+egg+cheese+garlic&submit=Search

So somehow those additional inputs need to add their text to the first ?s= with just a +... Any help is massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you kidding??

The `+` that you are seeking is simply a space. Have one text field, and when the form is submitted the spaces in between the words will be converted into `+`.

Comment: I need the 4 inputs as I am building a tool where people can search for 4 seperate items.

Comment: But they need to return one search result.

Comment: So you split the result using `explode` into an array or something and then program your logic to look for results with any one of the words from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you have a lot of problems, but before we get deep into them let me tell you that your "output" is in fact a get parameter, or a URL. Now you should ***`NEVER`*** use the same id for different tags (!!!). If you think about a valid reason to do that, then think again.

Change your form as follows:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://sitename.com/">
 <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Search"   />
 <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Search"  />
 <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Search"  />
 <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Search"  />
 <input type="hidden" name="s" id="s" />
 <div class="clear_space"></div>
 <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
 </form>
```

and then implement a [form submit event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) to calculate your value and assign to your input field. Cheers.

EDIT:

Use the following js code to run before you submit your form:

```
//...
var value = "";
$(".field").each(function(){
    value += ((value !== "") ? (" ") : ("")) + $(this).val();
});
$("#s").val(value);
//...
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a stupid oversight. I was just copying the inputs to create the 4 in the form to see what happened. I'll try and wrap my head around the form submit event and get back here if I have further questions.

I guess the .js will collect the 4 inputs and create the get query

Comment: The js will make sure that your hidden input contains the values to be searched for separated with space and after your hidden input contains the correct value, only then should your form be submitted.

Comment: Can I not just do this with php? A bit worried as it says the form submit event doesn't work in IE

Comment: What is "it" and where does it say it? You are using the site in your browser, PHP is executed on the server. You have to handle the form submit after the user clicked on the submit button and before you effectively submit your form. So you cannot do this on server-side, you cannot do this in PHP.

Comment: Alright...I understand I need the .js to handle the event now. Still a bit clueless.

I undertstand that on submit the form submit event will combine the values of the 4 inputs into the value of one hidden input and that will be the one submitted as a GET parameter, right? Any help on where to learn a little more about achieving this?

Comment: You are correct, the input field's value will be a parameter. I have edited my answer to add a js code sample which can be used to put the desired value into the input. I have not tested the code. Please tell me if you see any problems regarding that.